# pl/sql string conversion - regex

Tags: regex

I am very new to regex . and I am stuck on a particular issue above which I cant proceed. guidance from regex experts is greatly appreciated.

1) below is the pl/sql string which needs to be matched using regex.

```
TYPE T_OM_EPV2_LINE_REC_TYPE
IS
RECORD
(
ORDER_NO PS_OM_EPV2_LINE.ORDER_NO%type,
OM_SUBMIT_NBR PS_OM_EPV2_LINE.OM_SUBMIT_NBR%type);
```

2) this is the regex which I am trying to use

```
^TYPE [\w]+[\s]IS[\s]RECORD[\s]\([\s]([\w]+ [\w]+\.[\w]+%type.)
```

3) I am able to match ,

```
TYPE T_OM_EPV2_LINE_REC_TYPE
IS
RECORD
(
ORDER_NO PS_OM_EPV2_LINE.ORDER_NO%type,
```

but not `,OM_SUBMIT_NBR PS_OM_EPV2_LINE.OM_SUBMIT_NBR%type` (lastline)

4) rootcause being when the regex trying to match lastline, but its devoid of the first four lines.

5) I tried capturing and repeating regex concepts (to repeat the last before line making it as a group) but still did not achieve the output.

Any advice or insights on this please ?

Comment: Do you mean you want something like `^TYPE \w+\s+IS\s+RECORD\s+\([^()]*\)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/uml0nS/1))?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply wiktor. It worked . But I didn't get what does [^()]*\ imply in regex

Comment: Does it work for *your* scenario? Are there any nested parentheses?

Comment: `[^()]*` matches 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`. Are there any nested parentheses?

Comment: Yes its perfect ... there wont be any nested parantheses , just out of curiosity what if nested parantheses come how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have no nested parentheses on the last lines, you may use

```
^TYPE \w+\s+IS\s+RECORD\s+\([^()]*\)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uml0nS/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string or line
- `TYPE`  - a literal substring
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `IS` - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `RECORD`  - a literal substring
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `[^()]*` - 0+ chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

To manage nested parentheses, you might replace `\([^()]*\)` with `(\((?:[^()]++|(?1))*\))`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uml0nS/2).

If you just want to match any text up to the last `;`, use `^TYPE \w+\s+IS\s+RECORD\s+(\([\s\S]*\))`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/uml0nS/3).

Comment: Thanks For the detailed explanation ! this solved my issue!